# playing video fullscreen mode in webview fragment android

Tags: android, webview, fragment, fullscreen

I have untypical problem. I have fragment with webview and I need to play video in fullscreen. I have no problems with it. But when screen orientation changes - fragment recreated. But I need to continue playing video in fullscreen.

I can't use `android:configChanges="orientation|screensize"` in `AndroidManifest` to `MainActivity`, because `MainActivity` has two different layout for `lanscape` and `portrait` mode.

Comment: could you share the code of fragment? I cant view videos fullscreen on a webview of fragment... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can programatically force the screen orientation to be landscape on your fragment, so if the user rotates it do not change(you said you want the video to be fullscreen only so no reason to change a thing when it rotates), and when your activity is open but the fragment not the override on onConfigurationChanged will not be called.

So simply add this on your **fragment**:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

It should works... if for any reason doesn't, try to use the same logic on onAttach/onDetach or to check the config change of the activity (if the fragment is open lock the orientation), but I think the code above should solve your problem ;]